# How to access storage file from .env file in Laravel

Tags: laravel, google-bigquery, laravel-environment

I created a JSON file to use BigQuery in my Laravel project => [BigQuery docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication). I put the file in the `storage` folder to limit its access.
I only need to access it from my `.env` file.

`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/storage/file.json'`

Naturally, I cannot access the folder that easily and I know there are ways to access it but creating a symbolic link would make the file accessible from anywhere and I don't want that. Is there a secure way to access that file in my .env file ? Or is there a better way, another folder in which I should put the JSON file ?

Comment: Preferred way is to use a config file that uses `.env` variables. Don't use `.env` vars directly

Comment: How can I implement that in this case ? Is there another file in which I can set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` ? Do I need to create a config file for this ?

Comment: The Laravel [Configuration manual](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration) should get you started, especially [Retrieving Environment Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#retrieving-environment-configuration). You can keep that file in the `storage` folder, just don't directly access `.env` variables

Comment: Can I put `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=` in `.env` and in a file in the `config` folder, I add a config like
```'google_app_cred' => env('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS', Storage::get('file.json'))``` ? It seems really wrong...